# Passing a lambda function as a parameter

Tags: java, function, lambda, parameters, java-8

I'm trying to create an equivalent to Javascript's [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in Java.

I have been able to do it with

```
ArrayList<String> data = myList.stream().map(e -> {
    return "test "+e;
}).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Here, `myList` is the initial `ArrayList` and `data` is the resulting `ArrayList`.

However, I find it very tedious to do that every time.

So I tried to create a generic function that would make my life easier :

```
public static ArrayList<?> map(ArrayList<?> list, Function<? super Object,?> callback){
    return list.stream().map(callback).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

And then calling it with:

```
ArrayList<String> data = DEF.map(myList,e -> {
    return "test "+e;
});
```

But I get the error

> [Java] The method map(ArrayList, Function) in the
>   type DEF is not applicable for the arguments (List, (
>   e) -> {})

How can I edit my generic function to accept the lambda I'm using?

Comment: Ah, it's complaining about `List` vs. `ArrayList`. You should program to interfaces, i.e. change the parameter to `List<?>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should define your method with two generic type parameters - the element type of the source list, and the element type of the target list :

```
public static <S,T> ArrayList<T> map(ArrayList<S> list, Function<S,T> callback)
{
    return list.stream().map(callback).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

It would also be better to use the `List` interface instead of `ArrayList`:

```
public static <S,T> List<T> map(List<S> list, Function<S,T> callback)
{
    return list.stream().map(callback).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Example of usage:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList (1,2,3,4);
List<String> datai = map(myList ,e -> "test " + e);
```

Output:

```
[test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4]
```